# Django HtmlCalendar как перевести месяц на русский язык?

Tags: html, django, django-admin, django-orm

Разрабатываю HTMLCalendar с событиями на Django и не знаю как перевести месяц на русский язык, вывод в английском формате, а мне нужно на русском, может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой ?

```
    def formatmonth(self, withyear=True):
    events = Event.objects.filter(start_time__year=self.year, start_time__month=self.month)

    cal = f'\n'

    cal += f'<div class="row calendar-month-name pb-4 d-flex justify-content-center">{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}</div>\n'
```

в этой функции месяц выводится на английском языке. Если кто знает как перевести, подскажите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

В settings.py укажите настройки:

```py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Это задаст региональные настройки для Django.

Возможно потребуется указать формат вывода

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'd E Y' #26 ноября 2020
```

Принудительное использование в коде:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import dateformat

# Форматирование даты
you_date = dateformat.format(datetime.now(), settings.DATE_FORMAT)
```

Или в коде шаблона

```
{{you_date|date:'d-m-Y'}}  # 26-11-2020
```